# How can I see if all elements of a list are contained in a string

Tags: python

I'm getting some links on a webpage with Beautiful soup that match a certain condition. Here is the code for that,

```
    url = 'http://www.somesite.com/stats/'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    links_list = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'stats'}, href=True)
```

Links list is a list of about 10 different links and text with the same html tags. I have some words in a list that I would like to check against the text of these links. Basically, I am trying to see if all of the elements of my listt list exist in the string between the html tags for the elements of the links_list list.

Here is an example.

```
listt = ['big', 'letters']
for link in links_list[:]:
    for word in listt:
        if word not in link.get_text().lower():
            links_list.remove(link)
```

I thought this would be the proper route to go since I am iterating through a copy of the list. All the resources I've come across have said to create a copy of the list and iterate through. I am receiving the following error though.

```
  File "src\stats_finder.py", line 59, in find_item
    links_list.remove(link)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

In my situation, I would like to be left with the one link that contains all of my keywords in it's text between its html tags. Am I going about this the wrong way or is there possibly a more efficient way to do this? I looked into using all() but I couldn't devise a solution there either.

Comment: Ahhhh. I see now that I get that error because I'm trying to remove link from links_list after I already removed it on the first iteration of that 'for word in listt:' loop. I guess I just need to raise an exception for that error then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a shorter way to do this with the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) funtion.

```
listt = ['big', 'letters']
links_set = set(['hello', 'hi', 'big', 'cccc', 'letters', 'anotherword'])

all_are_present = all([word in links_set for word in listt]) # True
```

## Edit

I think what you were trying to do was check if each word in `listt` was in the text string of all html elements, in which case this would be:

```
listt = ['big', 'letters']
links_text_list = ['hello letters', 'big hi letters', 'big superman letters']

all_are_present = all([word in text for word in listt for text in links_text_list]) # False because "hello letters" doesn't have big
```

But since you only want those links that have all words in `listt` present, you can use the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#filter) function.

```
links_with_all_words = list(filter(lambda text: all([word in text for word in listt]), links_text_list))
print(links_with_all_words) # ['big hi letters', 'big superman letters']
```

Comment: This would be the best way to do it and it answers my question best so I will accept it. I will stick with the list solution though since all() will just return true or false and I will need to end up using link['href'] for further parts of my program.

Comment: @UCProgrammer I think I misunderstood what you were asking earlier and I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar problem

```
listt = ['big', 'letters']
for link in links_list[:]:
    _found = False 
    for word in listt:
        if word not in link.get_text().lower():
            _found = True
    if _found :
        links_list.remove(link)
```

[Python: ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686558/python-valueerror-list-removex-x-not-in-list)

Comment: Thanks. I edited your answer to make _found = False in the first for loop but other than that it works great! My assumption is that this would be faster than a try except clause too. Am I right or would the time be insignificant?

Comment: Yes it would be faster than try, except.